# How to change Key value string to JSON for a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2019. I have data in a table like this:

| Resource | Tags | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prod | project:kentico, tenant:abc, environment:production | 1000 |
| Prod | project:App services, tenant:abc, environment:production, Provider:abc | 2000 |

I want the tags column to be changed to json format to look like this:

| Resource | Tags | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prod | {"project":"App services", "tenant":"abc","environment":"production"} | 1000 |
| Prod | {"project":"App services", "tenant":"abc","environment":"production","Provider":"abc"} | 2000 |

Comment: Both options are bad. This schema cries out for an additional table.

Comment: I dont think the schema needs an additional table. The goal here is to convert a string key value pair to readable Json Format.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that neither commas (`,`) or colons (`:`) can appear in the values, you could just use `REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT Resource,
       CONCAT('{"',REPLACE(REPLACE(Tags,', ','","'),':','":"'),'"}') AS Tags,
       Cost
FROM (VALUES('Prod','project:kentico, tenant:abc, environment:production',1000),
            ('Prod','project:App services, tenant:abc, environment:production, Provider:abc',2000))V(Resource,Tags,Cost);
```

If your data isn't as well formed, I would suggest *not* doing this in SQL Server, and using something else that has good string manipulation functionality. Or, better yet, fix the process that is inserted the data in the first place to provide normalised data or proper JSON (this is the real solution).

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to use `String_Split()` and some prayers.

```
SELECT Resource, 
       Tags, 
       '{' + STRING_AGG('"' + REPLACE(value, ':', '":"') + '"', ',') + '}' as jsonvalue 
FROM test 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(Tags, ' ', ''), ',') 
GROUP BY Resource, Tags;
```

I agree with Larnu though that SQL Server is a terrible platform to be doing this work. Definitely feels more appropriate to pull this out into python and monkey around in there where a proper JSON library can be used to get the final result (and deal with error handling for all the edge cases that are likely to pop up).

Comment: Definitely a large amount of prayers. Unless the OP is on Azure (and if Microsoft are sensible 2022+), then they don't have the option of getting the ordinal position from `STRING_AGG` so the order `STRING_AGG` puts the data back in could be *very* wrong.

Comment: @Larnu I agree, that's a concern, but I figured if it's actually json they will be dealing with downstream, it likely doesn't matter. At least I've never had to worry about ordinal when I've worked with json. I'm curious though, I don't have a sql server to play with, but have you ever seen or heard of `string_split()` changing order of values? I mean... I don't trust it at all not to, but the little bit of monkeying I've done, it's always come back in the same order it went in.

Comment: I sure I've seen at least one question here where someone wasn't getting the results they wanted with a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` alongside `STRING_SPLIT`, but if I did that was several years ago. The main thing is that it's specifically documented that function doesn't respect the ordering, which would at least *suggest* that there are edge cases where it won't.